# How to run two python application in docker

Tags: python, web-services, docker

I want to run two python applicaiton in docker with different ports.

My shell script is below, the name is serverRun.sh

```
exec python __server_code.py &
exec python server_time_test.py &
```

in dockerfile, I am trying to run these two python application

```
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "./serverRun.sh"]
```

It did not work. Any idea?

Comment: I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

You must have one process in foreground. So remove the last &. And don't use exec

```
cd /rfk-thrift/nlp_search
python __server_code.py &
python server_time_test.py
```

And this in Dockerfile:

```
RUN chmod +x ./serverRun.sh
CMD ./serverRun.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Your shell script must not terminate, so lock it within a while loop with a strong sleep.

Docker detects the termination of the entrypoint, and ends the container.

Eventually you might want to resort to an entrypoint (bash or other scripting languages) that is able to detect application crashes so your container quits on failure.

I published for you a fully-featured Bash entrypoint [here](https://github.com/kerfab/docker-entrypoint-multiproc/) which does exactly this, and more.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your run command just sets the file permissions, it doesn't actually execute the script. Perhaps change the run command.

Answer (score 0):

The `RUN` instruction is only referenced during build. It won't be running when you launch the container. You want to use `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD`